# Using a regex with text search in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have created a text index on the `num` field in the collection. Now while passing the string to search from the *text index*, I need to use a regex which has to be passed as a string to the `$search` variable.

My current query works fine but it doesn't work when I add a regex to it.

Current Query:

```
db.collection.find({$text:{$search:"1234 6789"}},{'id':1})
```

I need to add a regex/like query to the `$search` to make it something like

```
db.collection.find({$text:{$search:"/1234/ /6789/"}},{'id':1})
```

where I get all the values from the database that contain a pattern like "1234" OR "6789".

I did try the query but it gives me a `$search` needs a String error:

```
db.collection.find({$text:{$search:/1234/}},{'id':1})
```

Comment: If you want regex then text search will be useless to you (for multiple reasons), you want to delove to normal querying.

Comment: @Sammaye That being rectified, can I search multiple regex terms as a string.Basically I am trying to pass this query term from the client side itself to reduce the string building process on the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve this you should use the $regex MongoDB operator:

```
// Without options
db.collection.find({num: /1234|5678/i});

// Separate options property
db.collection.find({num: {$regex: /1234|5678/, $options: 'i'}});
```

To add multiple terms in the regex, use the | operator

[$regex docs and examples](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

Edit:

For querying records using an array of values the `$in` operator can be used:

[$in docs and examples](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)

Comment: How can I add multiple regex terms to this. Like /1234/ OR /5678/

Comment: okay, So I did figure it out. Thanks. /1234|5678/ would be it!

Comment: If the keywords contain only numbers and letters that will work.